# Best way to write a WCF service returning custom XML having link to XSL

Tags: xml, wcf, xslt

I'm having a dynamicaly generated XML and local XSL. I'd like my clients to access this XML via URL. I'm expecting my clients to get HTML after they try to navigate the XML file.

What is the best way to implement such requirement?

Comment: Perform the xsl transformation on the server. Give clients a ready-made html.

Comment: Is the xml dynamically generated ? Is the xsl static ?

Comment: Yes. Actually, I'm fetching XML from another URL, which I'd like to update. I want to add a reference to my XSL, so that it converts it into HTML.